# Prove that $P(\tau<\infty)=1$ and find the distribution of $X_\tau$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning, stopping-times

> Let $\{X_n\}_{n\ge1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with distribution $\mu$. For $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}):=\text{Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$}$ with $\mu(A)\in(0,1)$, define
> \begin{align*}
> \tau=\inf{\{k\ge1, X_k\in A\}}
> \end{align*}
> (1) Prove that $P(\tau<\infty)=1$.

> (2) Prove that $X_\tau$ has distribution given by
> \begin{align*}
> P(X_\tau\in H)=\frac{\mu(H\cap A)}{\mu(A)},\quad H\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).
> \end{align*}

I know that $\tau$ is a stopping time with respect to $F_n:=\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$, in particular $\tau$ is a hitting time but I cannot figure out how to use this information to solve the problem. I feel like this is a pretty standard question and I have overthought myself into frustration with it, any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a family of i.i.d r.vs with distribution $\mu$. Let $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ be such that $\mu(A) \in (0,1)$. Define $\tau_A := \inf \{ n \ge 1 : X_n \in A \}$.

a) Note that $\tau_A$ has geometric distribution with parameter $\mu(A)$. Indeed, for $n \ge 1$:
$$ \mathbb P(\tau_A = n) = \mathbb P(X_1,...,X_{n-1} \not \in A, X_n \in A) = \mu(A)(1-\mu(A))^{n-1} $$
So (since $\mu(A) \in (0,1)$ !)
$$ \mathbb P(\tau_A < \infty) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(\tau_A = n) = \mu(A)\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-\mu(A))^{n-1} = \frac{\mu(A)}{1-(1-\mu(A))} = 1 $$

b) Let $X_{\tau_A}(\omega) = X_{\tau_A(\omega)}(\omega)$ (it is well defined up to the set of measure $0$)

Let any $H \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. We have:
$$ \mathbb P(X_{\tau_A} \in H) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_n \in H \cap \{ \tau_A = n \}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(\{X_1,...,X_{n-1} \not \in A\} \cap  \{X_n \in H \cap A \}) $$

Last equality, during to the fact, that since $\tau_A = n$, we need every $X_1,...,X_{n-1}$ not to fall into $A$, and $X_n$ must fall into $A$ and $H$ simultaneously. Since they are independent, we get it is equal to $(1-\mu(A))^{n-1} \cdot \mu(H \cap A)$, so:
$$ \mathbb P(X_{\tau_A} \in H) = \mu(A\cap H) \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-\mu(A))^{n-1} = \frac{\mu(A \cap H)}{\mu(A)}$$

Comment: This is brilliant! And exactly the detail that I needed to see, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!